The time complexity of $yx^\top$ where $x,y \in \mathbb R^n$ are non-sparse vectors?
I want to know the computational complexity of the multiplication $yx^\top$ where $x,y \in \mathbb R^n$ are non-sparse vectors, i.e., this is an outer product. What is also the computational complexity in the special case $y=x$, i.e., $xx^\top$.

Naively, given that the matrix is not sparse, you need to construct an $n^2$ matrix where each element of this matrix is a product of two numbers (constant time). So $O(n^2)$. Same applies for $x x^T$
